# Revel with mgo.v2 - How to return all data from a collection as json?

Tags: go, bson, mgo, revel

I'm trying to build an API endpoint using Revel for Go.

My models/models.go looks like this -

```
type Category struct {
Name string        `bson:"name"`
Slug  string        `bson:"slug"`}

func GetCategories(s *mgo.Session) *Category {
var results []Category
Collection(s).Find(nil).All(&results)
return results}
```

My controllers/book.go looks like this -

```
type Category struct {
*revel.Controller
revelbasic.MongoController}

func (c Category) Categories() revel.Result {
b := models.GetCategories(c.MongoSession)

return c.RenderJson(b)}
```

I've configured my conf/routes like this -

```
GET /categories Book.Categories
```

When I run the code, I get this error -

[cannot use results (type []Category) as type *Category in return argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBKQE.png)

I understand that I'm doing something wrong with the database query.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code is because of type mismatch between function `GetCategories`'s return value declaration and what you are actually returning. To fix, change the return type to return a slice of results:

```
func GetCategories(s *mgo.Session) []Category {
    var results []Category
    Collection(s).Find(nil).All(&results)
    return results
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was playing around with the code and wrote exactly this later on and saw your answer now! Thank you!